# Use alias name in variable name in ObjectiveC class

Tags: objective-c

I have a class called Node

```
@interface Node : NSObject
{
    Node* _prev;
    Node* _next;
    id    _data;
}
```

and I want to use for **Double Linked List** and **Binary Search Tree**.

But in Binary Search Tree, I would like to change **_prev** and **_next** to use **_left** and **_right**,

I'm wondering whether I can use an alias name **_left** for **_prev** and **_right** for **_next** so that my Node class can be used in **Double Linked List** and **Binary Search Tree**.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should define those fields as properties, not instance variables.

```
@interface Node : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *prev;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *next;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *left;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Node *right;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) id data;
@end
```

Then, in your implementation, you implement a custom getter and setter for left and right, like so...

```
- (Node *)left {
    return _prev;
}

- (void)setLeft:(Node *)left {
    _prev = left;
}

- (Node *)right {
    return _next;
}

- (void)setRight:(Node *)right {
    _next = right;
}
```

By defining both the getters and setters for left and right, you avoid (auto-)synthesizing instance variables, which would just go unused.